# How to make a constraint to only allow maximum number of rows to equal some data

Tags: sql, sql-server, check-constraints

I want to make a database for let's say an airline that has a maximum number of flights that can be booked for each flight.

I created this table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Airline
(
    FlightNum char(6),
    PassengerFirstName varchar(30),
    PassengerLastName varchar(30),
    PassengerAddress varchar(50),
    DateOfBirth date,
    FlightDate date
)
```

I want to have a `CONSTRAINT` that will only allow a specific number of flights to be booked per flight number per date, so let's say I want flight number `AIR001` to have a maximum of 5 passengers and flight number `AIR002` can have max of 6 passengers, each day.

So I tried adding this `CONSTRAINT`

```sql
CONSTRAINT ck_Airline_flight_num_maximum_bookings_exceeded 
    CHECK(COUNT(FlightNum) < CASE FlightNum WHEN 'AIR001' THEN 5 WHEN 'AIR002' THEN 6 END)
```

But I get this error:

> An aggregate may not appear in a computed column expression or check constraint.

What `CONSTRAINT` can I use? And is there a better way to do it than with a `CASE` statement?

Comment: If `FlightNum` is meant to contain a `int` why is it a `char`?

Comment: Its not an int as its 'AIR001' etc.

Comment: Confused by the logic you're trying to apply here. Sounds like you need a table of flights with a `maxqty` or similar value which you can check against before inserting a row and raise the appropriate error.

Comment: Yes I need it to check if it's exceeded max quantity of passengers allowed on the flight for that flight number for that day but first I tried to check only the flight number qty and I get the error so my question is how do I make such a `constraint`

Comment: A `CONSTRAINT` checks the validity of a row, and *just* that row. You can't check the values of others rows in a `CONSTRAIT`. If you *must* enforce such behaviour you'd have to do so with a well written trigger.

Comment: `Airline` is a TERRIBLE name for your table. But your first issue to address is how to know the maximum number of passengers allowed on any given flight. That changes over time depending on the type of plane and its configuration. At least that's correct for real life but perhaps this is just a learning exercise? Regardless, somewhere that characteristic should be recorded - probably in a parent table. So let's add that table and the appropriate RI constraints (primary, unique, and foreign keys) to your DDL.

Comment: Best way to do this normally is to have a column with a `check` constraint that must be between 1 and 6, then you add that to the primary key of the table along with `FlightNum`. Although I agree that a flight can change so it's probably best to just have a separate table with possible `FlightSeats`

Answer (score -1):

Use a trigger instead of a constraint as you cannot use aggregate functions for a constraint.

```
Create Trigger TriggerFlightNum 
    On Airline
    AFTER INSERT 
    As
        If ((Select COUNT(FlightNum) From Airline) > (SELECT TOP 1 CASE FlightNum WHEN 'AIR001' THEN 5 WHEN 'AIR002' THEN 6 END FROM Airline))
           RollBack Transaction
```